# Throw an exception without reference its host assembly?

Tags: .net, exception, reference

I have an assembly that is a plugin to a system A (it implements IASystemPlugin interface). The system A is a component of a system B. I want to throw an exception from the plugin to the System B level. Unfortunately, both systems A and B handle all known exceptions and re-throw all unknown ones, so I have to throw B.SystemBException instance.

As a system A client, I had no references to B classes and it's better if I will not (all references, except system ones, should be registered on the level A, it means 30+ B assemblies to be registered). In this case, am I able to instantiate the looking-very-simple B.SystemBException class?

Any hacking methods will be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: You exclude the thing you *have* to do.  Hardly necessary to reference *30* assemblies, one is enough.  The one that declares the exception type.

Comment: To make it work, I have to register my assembly as "plugin" to the system A. If "plugin" contains references to non-system assemblies, all of them should be registered as "plugins" too. Otherwise Register() method returns false. Recursively, I have to register all referenced assemblies for my referenced assembly, etc, so it's more than 30, that is too much for me to instantiate a little exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you might be able find the class through Reflection and create an instance of it. But, Are you sure you want to do this? I am assuming that the system interfaces were built to accomodate such content?

In any event, I assume you have access to that class since you are getting loaded by the other assembly. See this for starting it out: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Reflection.aspx

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: That should work, though I will have to find assembly to load it. I thought about something like GUIDs in COM: implement my own class in a way making system B think the exception is their own one.